# Why is pianist usually stressed on the /pi/?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

"Pianist" is usually pronounced /ˈpiənɪst/, with /piˈænɪst/ as an acceptable variant only in the US and Canada, according to Wiktionary.

I'm not sure why the pronunciation /ˈpiənɪst/ would be more common though. If we were just adding an -ist, a suffix that as far as I know generally doesn't change the stress of a word, we would expect /piˈænoʊ/ → /piˈænɪst/.

Looking at the etymology, "piano" and is derived from Italian "pianoforte" (/pjanoˈfɔrte/). "Pianist" is derived from French "pianiste" (/ˈpja.nist/), which is stressed similarly to the Italian "pianoforte" – the /i~j/ glide is much more marginal than the /a/.

also, <s>[it sounds like a certain other word that's pronounced /ˈpi.nɪs/.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pianist)</s>

Comment: In French, *pianiste*, like nearly all French words, is very mildly stressed on the last syllable, which in this case is *nist*. And the [Italian](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/pianista) *pianista* is also stressed on the *nist*

Comment: You think stresses follow a pattern?  Then explain photograph, photography, photographic.

Comment: @Peter Shot I expected that stress for French in general, but it seemed that the Wiktionary recording and Google Translate had it stressed on the first syllable.

Comment: @GEdgar: All three of those words follow pretty regular stress patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Although *-ist* usually doesn’t change stress, there are other words with this kind of stress difference. For example, *Narcissus* and *narcissist.* This doesn’t explain it, but it does suggest that there may actually be a weak preference to stress the antepenult of words of more than two syllables that end in *-ist.*